# Subscription mails of SSRS not being fired after moving SSRS to new server

Tags: reporting-services

I just moved my SSRS in a new server. The reports have moved fine with subscriptions but the mails are not being triggered. What all I need to check?

I checked logs and could find no error. Even the report subscription tabdoes not say report failed etc.

What could be the issue?

Comment: 3.Verify that <UrlRoot> is set to the report server URL address. This value is set when you configure the report server and it should be filled in already. If it is not set, type the report server URL address.--checked

6.Verify that <SendUsing> is set to 2. If it is set another value, the report server is not configured to use a remote SMTP service.--checked

Answer (score 0):

Verify that email setup is done properly in the new instance of SSRS by means of creating a new subscripion. If when creating a new subscription you don´t have the email choice, then you need to go to SSRS Configuration Manager and setup in the email tab your smtp server.
You can see how it looks like in this image [screenshot](http://bhushan.extreme-advice.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/11-Email-Configuration-in-SSRS-with-SMTP-in-Windows-Server-2008R2.png)

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi.Thanks for the comment.These things were done already. New analysis. The mails got triggered over the weekend way after they were scheduled. I checked again today but again the mail wasnt triggered on the specified time (given today). So I am assuming it is not config related. What else could it be?If I speak with network team what should I ask them to check?

Comment: The issue is resolved. It was due to wrong set time of DB server.

Comment: Ok, check the SQL Server Agent. Sometimes it's down or it has manual start. As you probably know any subscription is stored as well as a new job in the SQL Server Agent which is the final responsible of triggering the execution (the job has a funny command identifying the subscription GUID).